# Practical example of a non-measurable maximum likelihood estimator

Tags: maximum-likelihood, measure-theory

[This post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/430954/example-of-a-non-measurable-maximum-likelihood-estimator) gives an example of a situation where the MLE is not measurable. However, this doesn't seem to be a situation that you would ever encounter in practice.

Is there a more practical example of a situation where the MLE is not measurable? To be more specific, is there an example that does not rely on the axiom of choice? If such an example exists, and we happen to be put in a situation where we want to estimate a parameter, but the MLE is not measurable, what should we do?

Answer (score 1):

So I think whether or not an example is *practical* is a little ambiguous. However, with regard to the *axiom of choice* (AC), I think the answer is **no**. That is, if we want to **construct** an example in which $\hat\theta$ is non-measurable this will **require** AC. The reason for this is simply that in order [to construct a non-measurable set of real numbers we need to employ AC](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133999/can-one-construct-a-non-measurable-set-without-axiom-of-choice). And, of course, we will need a non-measurable set inside our measure space to construct a non-measurable function.

Interestingly, my understanding is that while we cannot **construct** an example without AC it is still possible that a non-measurable $\hat\theta$ could **exist**! The reason for this is that the existence of a non-Lebesgue measurable is consistent with Zermelo-Fraenkel (ZF) axioms. That is, [a non-measurable set does not imply AC](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133999/can-one-construct-a-non-measurable-set-without-axiom-of-choice). I don't think this really answers your question about practicality but it is an interesting point (assuming my reading is correct).

**So what do we do about this?** Well, I am going to give a bit of a *dodging* :) answer here. One of the more classical assumptions in MLE is that $\Theta$ is compact and the criterion is continuous in $\theta$. This will be enough for the measurability of $\hat\theta$. Another possibility is to work with outer probability measures when generalizing to the case of extremeum estimators (there is an example of this generalization in Chapter 5 of Van der Vaart (1998)). Specifically, we will relax uniform convergence to,

$$P^*[\sup_{\theta\in\Theta} |\hat Q(\theta)-Q(\theta)|>\epsilon]\to 0$$

a.s. in outer probability. where each of these events $\{\sup_{\theta\in\Theta} |\hat Q(\theta)-Q(\theta)|>\epsilon\}$ need not be measurable. But this only lets us bypass measurability issues as we approach the limit. It seems that as long as $(\Theta, \mathcal{A})$ is a separable measurable space then that is enough to [guarantee measurability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1251393/when-is-the-maximum-likelihood-estimator-measurable).

Comment: First, thank you for your thoughtful response. About your first point, what if we consider a situation where the sample space is not the real numbers? One practical scenario is if our statistical experiment involves, say, tossing a coin and throwing a die. Suppose that we know the probability of the coin landing on heads, but we do not know any of the probabilities regarding the die (and our sigma field reflects this). Then the indicator function of whether a "1" was rolled will not be measurable. Perhaps in a situation such as this, we could come up with a non-measurable MLE?

Comment: I fail to see how this random variable would be [non-measurable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-measurable_set). This is simply an event whose probability we do not know.

Comment: That wikipedia article seems to be referring to Lebesgue measurability. I'm talking about measurability in general; see for example, section 13 and section 20 of Probability and Measure by Billingsley. Given an arbitrary probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$, a random variable is a function $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is measurable $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: In my example above, I can simply define $\Omega = \{(H, 1), (T, 1), (H, 2), (T, 2), \dots ,\}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ so that it contains $\{(H,1),(H,2), \dots, (H,6)\}$ (the event that heads is flipped) but not $\{(H,1), (T, 1)\}$ (the event that "1" is rolled), for example. I'm wondering if we can come up with a probability model such that the MLE is not $\mathcal{F}$ measurable.

Comment: You can obviously define a $\sigma$-algebra that will not include some set. However, notice that this is not the procedure that we use in MLE or when we define random variables. Rather we use the $\sigma$-algebra **generated** by the random variable. In your example, this would of course be included as the union of $(H,1)$ and $(T,1)$.